# What happens when you do "import someModuleName from someModule" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, npm

I understand that when you want to reuse a module at several places. You do:    `module.exports  = yourModuleClassName` in to make that module exportable.

Next, when you want to use it in other places, you simply import it, like so: `import yourModuleClassName from 'yourmodulePath'`

I totally understand the above concept and I have no doubts in that. Today, I am more concerned about, What happens when you import a package:

Like importing redux-form package:

So first I do: `npm install redux-form`

What happens next is I do: `import redux-form from redux-form`
to use it in my module.

Now, When I look into an npm installed package. For example; when I look into the `redux-form` folder under my `node-modules` folder. It's a complete project with a `server.js` and `package.json` of its own, same happens with other `npm package installs` also. I totally get that they are an independent modules(but a bigger one) and they work in the same way as my local independent modules.

But I didn't find any `module.exports` there, so how are they importable. Of course, `NODEJS` is doing some magic to make them importable all across my projects. But, how exactly it is doing that. Let's say I keep a module inside my node_modules folder, but I don't it to be importable(I know no body would do it, Just curious!). If `NODE` is responsible to make it importable, how does it take care about the files which I don't want importable, but I want them to lie in the `node_modules` folder.

Moreover, these modules have there own `server.js` and `webpack.configs` do they get executed when I call import on those packages, if not then how exactly do they work.

I asked this question because I am trying to make an independent `npm package`, and I want to understand how they work. There is a similar question; [What happens when you import a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280157/what-happens-when-you-import-a-package)
but it is more inclined toward python. Can anyone explain this question for NODEJS. If there are any available resorces online, please guide me there, I will highly appreciate that.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

When you import a package installed with npm, node follows these steps:

1. It finds the first `node_modules` folder which

   - is contained in an ancestor folder of the file you are importing the package from AND
   - contains a folder named as the package you are importing
2. If the package has a `package.json` file and that file has a `main` field,

   - node loads the file set in the `main` field
3. Otherwise, node loads the `index.js` file.

(Source: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together)

---

> Moreover, these modules have there own server.js and webpack.configs do they get executed when I call import on those packages, if not then how exactly do they work.

`webpack.config.js` is the configuration for Webpack, a build tool. Webpack is only executed by the developer of `redux-form` before publishing the package on npm: when you `npm install` it, it is already built/compiled

Inside a node package, `server.js` is just a normal file (like `foo.js`). It has a special meaning only if it is in your *application* root: it gets executed when you run `npm start`.

---

*PS* You are mixing two ways of using modules: CommonJS and ES6. It works because you are *transpiling* your modules (maybe using Babel, or any other transpiler), but it might not work when node will natively support ES6 modules.

**Which are the differences between CommonJS and ES6 modules?**

```
// commonjs
module.exports = yourModuleClassName;
// ES6
export default yourModuleClassName;

// commonjs
exports.something = yourExportedVariable;
// ES6
export { yourExportedVariable as something }

// commonjs
var importedModule = require("module-path");
// ES6
import importedModule from "module-path";

// commonjs
var something = require("module-path").something;
// ES6
import { something } from "module-path";
```